# FrameLayout layout_weight programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a `FrameLayout` programmatically as follows(this view will float on the the bottom center of a `LinearLayout`):

```
    FrameLayout bottomFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
    bottomFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM));
```

Since I set `layout_width=0dp`, I would like to also set `layout_weight` to control the width.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams (int width, int height, float weight)` constructor since `FrameLayout` is child of `LinearLayout` therefore you are setting params for child in `LinearLayout`.

Edit:

```
 FrameLayout bottomFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,mWeight);
 lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM;
 bottomFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: if i use LinearLayout.LayoutParams to set weight how do i set the gravity?

Comment: Try assigning value to `gravity` field, like `layoutParamsObject.gravity = Gravity.SOME_OF_THE_CONSTANTS`

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski FrameLayout isn't a child of LinearLayout according to the reference see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html and FrameLayout.LayoutParams isn't a child of LinearLayout.LayoutParams see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html. Is your answer outdated?

Comment: @soriak I believe the child in this case does not mean "inherits from class" but rather "is child of the concrete LinearLayout object mentioned in question"

Comment: but it doesn't work. I getting an Exception: `..LinearLayout.LayoutParams cannot be cast to FrameLayout.LayoutParams..`. Answer is outdated

Comment: @L'Esperanza It's not outdated, check your imports, maybe you have static import for `LayoutParams` inner class

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski, everything was good with my imports and other things. I has already solved this problem on another stackoverflow. Thanks for answer.