# Handling ClassCastException when we set LayoutParams programmatically

Tags: android, classcastexception, layoutparams

I am doing like this -

### OPTION 1:

***Setting params first time:***

```
FrameLayout fLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().
findViewById(R.id.headlines_fragment); 
fLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.
LayoutParams(310, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

***Setting params second time:***

```
FrameLayout fLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().
findViewById(R.id.headlines_fragment); 
fLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.
LayoutParams(500, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, .03f));
```

Although I am setting the LayoutParams in my other parts of application as well but my suspect was the above code.

So I changed the above code to be -

### OPTION 2:

***Setting params first time:***

```
FrameLayout fLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().
findViewById(R.id.headlines_fragment); 
fLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(310,
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

***Setting params second time:***

```
FrameLayout fLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().
findViewById(R.id.headlines_fragment); 
fLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(500, 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, .03f));
```

However, setting the param second time in `OPTION 2` is giving the compile time exception -

*The constructor FrameLayout.LayoutParams(int, int, float) is undefined*

**So my two questions -**

1) *Am I doing right to set the layout params to FrameLayout i.e following 
   OPTION 2 instead of OPTION 1 ?*

2) *How to remove this compile time error?*

**My XML -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.25" />

    <FrameLayout
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Log -**

```
Stack Trace- java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$LayoutParams
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1319)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1041)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2191)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why you changed from first option to second option? ie from LinearLayout layoutparams to Framelayout params?

Comment: I changed from first option to second because I am getting `ClassCastException` somewhere in my code but don't know where. I thought that its my first option that is causing it and so I changed it to second option i.e. from LinearLayout layoutparams to Framelayout params.

Comment: First code can't be the reason of classcast exception. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8569947/609782

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you are doing wrong, there is no such constructor for `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`. constructor for `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` which takes `int, int, float` is for `weight` setting (last float value), `FrameLayout` don't support weights

2) if you really need this weight `.03f` you have to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` or eventually you might calculate (measure) height/width and in second initiation of params use this value instead `wrap_content`/`match_parent`

Comment: See my updated XML. I was setting the layout params of `FrameLayout `to `LinearLayout` by using `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. Is it wrong ?

Comment: you should set `LayoutParams` of parent, not the view for which you are setting. so if your `headlines_fragment` is still inside `LinearLayout` then you should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. LayourParams corresponds to `android:layout_blahblah` (width, margin etc.) xml params and they are used to inflate view in it's parent, so params should correspond to parent params form for unique values like `layout_centerHorizontal` for `RelativeLayout`. if you want only width and height you might use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` (all `LayoutParams` extends it)